# How to embed slideMenu into android 2.3.3 project?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to embed `slidemenu` into my android application that supports android 2.3.3 and below.

But i keep getting the error below. What could be the problem and how can i solve it

```
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] Versions found are:
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] Path: D:\Android\library\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample]  Length: 385685
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample]  SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] Path: D:\Android\SlidingMenuExample\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample]  Length: 556198
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample]  SHA-1: 4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
[2013-09-25 08:47:23 - SlidingMenuExample] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045568/jar-mismatch-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the android-support-v4.jar from your project's libs and try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right clic on the project and library "**Android Tools/Add Support Library...**" then **clean** all projects