# Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list

Tags: android, eclipse, shared-libraries, dependency-properties

I know there's a couple of threads dealing with the same issue, but none of the solutions are working for me.

I am building an app that uses both the Google and the Facebook SDK. When launching Eclipse, I get this error message:

```
[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] Found 2 versions of google-play-services.jar in the dependency list,

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] Versions found are:

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] Path: /Users/***/Development/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/libs/google-play-services.jar

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***]     Length: 1501528

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***]     SHA-1: e5f81129dfb3d02df80126512bc98278ed2bb40a

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] Path: /Users/***/Development/my-app/libs/google-play-services.jar

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***]     Length: 103227

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***]     SHA-1: 70356edea26cc0bec4870d2cbd0eec6f0d2ffcae

[2014-03-02 11:40:40 - ***] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

I tried Android Tools ---> "Add support library..." with all three projects (Facebook SDK, Google SDK, My-App project), but the error remains. A lot of answers tell people to delete one jar or copy/paste jars ... but I'm fairly new to this and I don't wanna break anything.

What's the best way to go here?

Comment: try adding same version of support library jar file in all the dependent projects.

Comment: did you import one project and add `google-play-services.jar` to that? if yes,so remove old `google-play-services.jar` and create one API key with your SHA and put that on manifest file

Comment: I did so indeed. However, after importing the project, I created an API key with my SHA and put it in the manifest file. Should I still be getting that same error message?

Comment: Simply delete google-play-service lib from the project lib folder and clean one time.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem comes when multiple versions of the same jar file is used in the project (including the library project if added).The best practice is to delete the previous jar files and add a fresh updated same jar file in all the corresponding projects.

Refer this post,
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045627/1665507

Comment: @strawberrywine: yeah delete those 3 and add a updated same jar file in each of them.

Comment: Just noticed I can't delete them for Facebook and Google SDK. http://bit.ly/1ogFBAb