# how to generate support library again?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-support-library

I created an app with the minimum sdk-version 10 and I downloaded support library for the following manifest.xml.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Now I would like to use the minimum skd-version 7 for this same app. I changed the manifest.xml according to the follwing and I downloaded the support library again.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

But at that time, the following error occurred.

> [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] Versions found are:
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] Path: C:\trunk\MasterSource\Location\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location]    Length: 648327
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location]    SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] Path: C:\ABS\libs\android-support-v4.jar
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location]    Length: 621451
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location]    SHA-1: 5896b0a4e377ac4242eb2bc785220c1c4fc052f4
>   [2014-09-12 12:59:05 - Location] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

How can I add support library to make to compatible for android 2.x?

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ?

Comment: @NadirB no, I am now using eclipse adb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different android-support-v4.jar in your project and libraries projects.

Replace all of android-support-v4.jar with **\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar**

Hope it will solve your problem.

See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12045627/3582473

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because both the android-support-v4.jar is different.

To solve this error you just need to copy file from first project's lib folder and paste to second projects's lib folder.

finally clean and it's done. you will not see this error again.