# Facebook SDK causing errors in my android project

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to implement a Facebook login button to my Android application. I imported the SDK to my IDE (eclipse) but when I add the Facebook reference to my project errors show.
I'm using navigator drawer and volley lib in my project and that's where I have errors .

what I have to do to fix this error?

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] Versions found are:

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] Path: D:\Omar\Android\WorkSpace\facebook-android-
sdk-3.23.1\facebook-android-sdk-3.23.1\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp]   Length: 758727

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp]   SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] Path: D:\Omar\Android\WorkSpace\MyApp\MyApp\libs\android-support-v4.jar

[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp]   Length: 627582
[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp]   SHA-1: db0f122c99ef9f90dbab3fada6d191f2880cbb8e
[2015-03-18 15:22:52 - MyApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: *what i have to do to fix this error* start from reading 'em ... then do some research, then try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please post the errors you are getting.....

Comment: check out these 2 links.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056914/jar-mismatch-fix-your-dependencies     or    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045568/jar-mismatch-found-2-versions-of-android-support-v4-jar-in-the-dependency-list

Comment: Some people here are really too quick to down vote. I have a general policy of not down voting, so I may be coming from the opposite extreme. But this question really does not deserve the down vote. So I +1 to set things right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually easy to fix.

1. Right click on the Facebook-SDK project in eclipse
2. Go to Java build path
3. Under "Order and Export" Deselect (i.e. Uncheck) Android Private Libraries
4. Simultaneously clean and build both your project and the Facebook-SDK project